# Window.print() with A6 page size

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Here is my code. I need print with A6 page size.

```
var printWindow = window.open("../Recipt.htm?jobcardNum=" + jobCard, "Print Reciept", "resizable=0,width=520,height=520")
//var printWindow = window.open("All Records", "Print Panel", 'resizable=0,width=520,height=520');                           
printWindow.focus();
printWindow.print();
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What are you trying to accomplish? If your question is _'Can I pre-select a page size for printing?'_ the answer is no.

Comment: I need page print  with A6 size and I am using window.print(). Is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible if the user has a printer connected that is capable of printing an A6 page. However you cannot _force_ the user to print an A6 page through JavaScript.

Comment: User have force me to print as A6 page.

Comment: I think have there is no option with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

the simplest way to define page print size is by using @page attribute

[page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@page/size)